# Commiting project on svn repository from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I know how to commit project to the repository i.e. by doing right click on Project>Team>commit and then select the files to commit. My confusion is at this point while we select which files do we need to commit:

1) Do we need to select only java files and xml files?

2) Will it lead to any conflicts if we commit bin or other folders or files than java files and xml files?

It might sound so silly but it would be really very helpful if anyone throws light on these points! or give references to any good tutorial on commiting files to svn.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)   It is strongly NOT recommend to commit a bin folder or classes files.
It is recommended to commit only source files (Java) and resources (xml files, images etc.).

2)   If you commit the bin folder you will see a difference each time after a compilation.

Couple of additional clarifications why NOT to commit the result of the compilation (a bin 
folder or classes files):

1) You can compile your product form the same sources to the different platforms

2) It just take space in a source control repository

Comment: Thanks Michael, but just for knowledge can you please explain a bit on why we should not commit whole project and only source and resources and what happens if I accidently commit bin and the other person takes update. Will the other person face any conflicts or issues?

Comment: Don't commit the gen folder too.

Comment: bin contains the .dex files for your application. These files are executable on the Dalvik VM.
 
gen contains the files generated on your machine as a result of the build process. 

Files in these folders are automatically generated by eclipse when people on your team check out the project and run it so there is no need to commit them.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Michael and Mus! It really helped me understanding the things in better way but it would be great if you spare time in answering the other part of my question i.e Will the other person face any conflicts or issues if  I accidently commit bin and the other person takes update? If yes then how to resolve that?

Comment: I know I am asking too much of questions but this SVN sometimes creates blunders!!!!!